# mongodb gridfs to flat files

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

How do I convert a dumped mongodb to flat files?
I inherited a mongodb with a gridfs like

```
  foo.files.bson
  foo.chunks.bson
```

I imported them using mongorestore.
But now how can I dump each object to external file?
All the lengths are about 29,000 while the chunk sizes
are 262,144, so the chunks should be self contained.

```
> db.foo.files.find()[0]
{
    "_closed" : true,
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e9c69e93e3c092c02000001"),
    "chunkSize" : 262144,
    "comment" : ObjectId("4e9c69e93e3c092c02000000"),
    "compression" : "bz2",
    "filename" : "my/file",
    "is_dft" : true,
    "is_gw" : false,
    "length" : 22760,
    "md5" : "f58c497a0f6127fe70f8240c12d482b6",
    "sha512" : "19e3...a2338",
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2011-10-17T17:46:17.312Z"),
    "uploader" : null
}


> db.OUTCARs.chunks.find()[0]
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e9c69e93e3c092c02000002"),
    "n" : 0,
    "data" : BinData(0,"QlpoOTFsEAjf...UJA8CxbBA="),  ******* this is the data to save to a flat file
    "files_id" : ObjectId("4e9c69e93e3c092c02000001")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to read the files in the imported dump - the mongodb client tool for this job is mongofiles - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/

Just type mongofiles on the command prompt / terminal and you will see sub commands like put/get/list/search. Your answer lies in using get and list.